# gulp - wrap plugin (which uses through2) output with string

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-plugin, through2

I would like to know how exactly can I manipulate the output of my Gulp plugin so, for example, no matter how many files are passed to the plugin, it will wrap the output with a string. Currently I cannot know when does the last file is done.

The super simplified example below will iterate on 3 files and will create a new file named `output.js` and in it there will be three times the string `xxx` (xxxxxxxxx).

I would like the plugin **itself** to wrap the contents so the output will 
be: `+xxxxxxxxx+`.

**How can I do this**?
Thanks!

#### Gulpfile

```
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var concat      = require('gulp-concat');
var foo         = require('./index');

gulp.task('default', function() {
    gulp.src([a.html, b.html, c.html])
        .pipe(foo())
        .pipe(concat('output.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./test/output'))
});
```

#### The most basic gulp plugin (index.js):

```
var through2 = require('through2'),
    gutil    = require('gulp-util');

var PLUGIN_NAME = 'foo';

module.exports = function( options ){
    // through2.obj(fn) is a convenience wrapper around
    // through2({ objectMode: true }, fn)
    return through2.obj(function( file, enc, callback ){
        file.contents = new Buffer( 'xxx' );

        this.push(file);
        callback();
    });
}
```

I understand the files are currently simply returned modified, but what I don't understand is how to append text and return the concatenated result that I want, while keeping it OK with Gulp working standards.

---

The "real" plugin should actually wrap the files results with:

```
var foo = { FILES_CONTENT }
```

where `FILES_CONTENT` will actually be a a concatenated string of all the files:

```
"file_name" : "file_content",
"file_name" : "file_content",
...
```

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to do. What should `foo()` emit? One file with content `+xxxxxxxxx+`? Three files with contents `+xxx`, `xxx`, `xxx+`?

Comment: one file with `+xxxxxxxxx+`

Answer (score 3):

I would make the following changes to your **gulpfile.js**:

```
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var foo         = require('./index.js');

gulp.task('default', function() {
   return gulp.src(['a.html', 'b.html', 'c.html'])
     .pipe(foo({fileName:'output.js', varName:'bar'}))
     .pipe(gulp.dest('./test/output'))
});
```

Since your `foo()` plugin itself will concatenate all the files, there's no need to use `gulp-concat` at all. Instead your plugin should accept an option `fileName` that provides the name of the generated file. I've also added another option `varName` that will provide the name of the `var` in the output file.

I'll assume that **a.html**, **b.html** and **c.html** are simple HTML files, something like this:

```
<h1 class="header">a</h1>
```

As you've already realized you need to concat all the files in the plugin itself. That's not really difficult however and doesn't require a lot of code. Here's a **index.js** which does exactly that:

```
var through2 = require('through2'),
    gutil    = require('gulp-util'),
    path     = require('path'),
    File     = require('vinyl');

var PLUGIN_NAME = 'foo';

module.exports = function(options) {
  var files = { };
  var outputFile = null;
  return through2.obj(function(file, enc, callback){
    outputFile = outputFile || file;
    var filePath = path.relative(file.base, file.path);
    files[filePath] = file.contents.toString();
    callback();
  }, function(callback) {
    outputFile = outputFile ? outputFile.clone() : new File();
    outputFile.path = path.resolve(outputFile.base, options.fileName);
    outputFile.contents = new Buffer(
      'var ' + options.varName + ' = ' +
      JSON.stringify(files, null, 2) + ';'
    );
    this.push(outputFile);
    callback();
  });
}
```

Since you want to output a key/value mapping from file names to file contents our [`transformFunction`](https://github.com/rvagg/through2#transformfunction) just stores both of those things in a regular JavaScript object `files`. None of the input files themselves are emitted. Their names and contents are just stored until we have all of them.

The only tricky part is making sure that we respect the [`.base`](https://github.com/gulpjs/vinyl#filebase) property of each file as is customary for gulp plugins. This allows the user to provide a custom base folder using the [`base` option](https://gulp.readme.io/docs/gulpsrcglobs-options#section-options-base) in `gulp.src()`.

Once all files have been processed `through2` calls the [`flushFunction`](https://github.com/rvagg/through2#flushfunction). In there we create our output file with the provided `fileName` (once again making sure we respect the `.base` property).

Creating the output file contents is then just a matter of serializing our `files` object using `JSON.stringify()` (which automatically takes care of any escaping that has to be done).

The resulting **./test/output/output.js** will then look like this:

```
var bar = {
  "a.html": "<h1 class=\"header\">a</h1>\n",
  "b.html": "<h1 class=\"header\">b</h1>\n",
  "c.html": "<h1 class=\"header\">c</h1>\n"
};
```

Comment: Thank you **very much**. You have helped me a great deal and opened my eyes to the possibilities of `through2`. I come from the world of browser development and lack sufficient knowledge in Node. You have helped me in upgrading my gulp plugin [gulp-file-contents-to-keys](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-file-contents-to-keys)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the gulp pipeline technique (standard).
This means that you can use the [gulp-insert](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-insert) package in order 
to add the string xxx.

```
var insert = require('gulp-insert');

.pipe(insert.append('xxx')); // Appends 'xxx' to the contents of every file
```

You can also prepend, append and wrap with this package and it support of course the gulp standards.

So the full example will be:

```
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var concat      = require('gulp-concat');
var foo         = require('./index');
var insert      = require('gulp-insert');
gulp.task('default', function() {
    gulp.src([a.html, b.html, c.html])
        .pipe(foo()
        .pipe(insert.append('xxx'))
        .pipe(concat('output.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./test/output'))
});
```

Comment: I think you did not understand.. I wrote it very clearly that I would like this to happen **inside** the plugin **itself**, that is the essence of the question and what makes it so difficult. I think that I will have to internally concat all the files into a single result and wrap that result. it is a LOT of code :(